How to place point at end of current filename when using find-alternate-file
Billions of years ago (maybe in emacs18) the behavior of C-x C-v (find-alternate-file) changed.  The current behavior is described in the manual thus: "When C-x C-v reads the file name to visit, it inserts the entire default file name in the [mini]buffer, with point just after the directory part".  In the old behavior, point was left at the end of the filename.  That's the behavior I want.  How can I achieve it?

Define your own version of find-alternate-file and bind it to the keys you want. Or advise find-alternate-file. (And maybe it was as you say in Emacs 18, dunno, but at least since Emacs 20 the behavior has been the same as it is now.)

Why do you care? IMO, the current default is probably more convenient: if you want to accept the default, you just press RET and that's it; if you don't want to accept it, you press C-k and fill in the filename. In the latter case, with the old default, you'd have to backspace over the filename or delete it in "word" pieces. The only advantage of the old default is if you want to change the suffix, but then you can do C-e to go to the end before changing the suffix.

Hi Drew - thanks, I had tried to imitate the def of find-alternate-file, but it's complex and I wasn't able to find the instruction that selects the placement of point.  And I don't understand what you mean by "Or advise find-alternate-file".  Can you be more specific?

Hi NickD - thanks for telling me what I should want.  I'll try to explain better: The default is the current file name, so it's never what I'll select (else, I wouldn't be trying to change it).  The desired filename is generally a slight variation of the current filename, and the change I want to make is usually at the end -- for example, add a digit.  Yes, I can use C-e to go to the end, and that's what I've been doing for many years, but now I'm having to do it several times a day for a project. I remember the previous behavior of the function, and it was better for my purposes.

Are you looking to change the behavior only in find-alternate-file?  Or is it OK to change the behavior in all find-*-file functions?

I think changing all find-*-file functions would be fine!  I don't use the others (or at least, not nearly as often).
